# Render specific model id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to take an example of a model (in this case, *Book*), and render a specific instance of that model by ID.

The model is just a basic scaffold generated model - usual `show` method;

```
def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @book }
    end
  end
```

I'm looking to embed an instance of this inside of the view:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
    <%= render :template "books/show", :book => 1 %>
</div>
```

There's something I'm doing wrong here, I can tell. But I don't know where to proceed from here! Any help is really appreciated. I know I need to somehow pass the book ID, but I can't figure out how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: You need to actually look up the book, something not appropriate in the template--using `:template` just renders the template, it doesn't execute the action. What's your actual goal? If you already have the book, are you in fact trying to render a partial for the book?

Comment: I do have the book, yes. A couple of them. I basically just want to render the show view inside of an existing div.

Comment: And I'm saying if you're rendering the book controller's "show" already, `@book` is already available. Are you trying to render a partial in the div? Is this in the book's view (show template) already?

Comment: I'm actually trying to render it in a different controller - which is why I'd heard of the `:template` function being used. In the code I provided, that's why I tried to provide an id or something with the render function - I know I need to somehow access it through `/books/show/1` but I can't seem to get that to work.

Comment: Then you either need to (a) get the book in the controller you *are* accessing, or (b) grab the info via Ajax. (There may be some other options; those are the easiest.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%= render :template "books/show", :book => 1 %>` only renders the partial, it doesn't *load* the page.
What you need to do is call the route `"books/show/#{book_id}"` from an iframe for example.

Comment: This works so far. I'm not a huge fan of iFrames, but I can format it easily enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe?

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
  <%= render 'books/show', book: @book %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable @book, you create in your controller is automatically made visible into the template. So, if your template show.html.erb is placed in the right place, then

```
<%= @book.title %>
```

should render the text (I assume the Book has an attribute title here).

I am not sure where the html you present is located. It does not make sense in show.html.erb, since you actually reference that file from there. If you would like to render a link to a book, then you should do

```
<%= link_to 'Link text', book_path(1) %>
```